# simple bar chart in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js, chart.js

I am trying to get charting working in Angular2 and cant seem to get it to work at all despite having a working code base for other functionality such as Flex-Layout...so i understand the basics of directives, components, declaring constructors etc...

I have followed a number of tutorials on D3 and Chart.Js including [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x296y5mErWI) but none seem to show every step I require or are for Angulatr1. I have cleaned out my code of most of the libs i have downloaded but currently have `"d3": "^4.5.0"`, and `"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^4.0.1",` npm'd.

Can anybody outline the steps to creating a simple, basic bar chart from hardcoded data array eg `[bar1:20, bar2:10]` found within the component?

Comment: You mention a bunch of different libraries. Which one exactly are you willing to use to generate your chart? Plain D3.js? Chart.js? ngx-charts?

Comment: I am currently working with ng2-charts but running into errors 'core.umd.js:3478 TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
    at assignAll (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:704:29)
'

i will updat emy Question

Comment: Author of ngx-charts here. You can either use the bar chart component that comes with the library, or build your own custom bar chart.

To use the bar component, take a look at the documentation and plunkr example here: https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-charts/content/charts/bar-vertical.html

You would have to change your data into the format that the chart accepts.

To build your own custom bar chart using the components of ngx-charts, you can take a look at this example custom bar component: https://github.com/marjan-georgiev/Angular-CLI-NG2D3-Demo/tree/master/src/app/custom-chart